# SET CONNECTION in PostgreSQL gives "unrecognized configuration parameter"

Tags: postgresql, connections

According to the PostgreSQL documentation, there appears to be support for [SET CONNECTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ecpg-sql-set-connection.html).

However, when I try to execute it from the psql prompt, I get

> ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "connection"

I'm well aware of [using \connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949876/how-to-switch-databases-in-psql/3949885#3949885) but I want to be able to switch databases within the execution of a .sql file.

Is this a bug in PostgreSQL?  Or does some flag need to be set to create the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Converting question comments into an answer*

*[Abelisto](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/88191/abelisto)*:

It seems that you missed a section of the documentation: [Chapter 34. ECPG - Embedded SQL in C](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ecpg.html). The PostgreSQL documentation is not ideal (but IMO it is much better then many others). Hint: to avoid inconveniences look at the page name in the address, for example `plpgsql-declarations.html` is about `DECLARE` variables in the `plpgsql` blocks and `sql-declare.html` is about `DECLARE` cursors in the pure SQL.

*[dezso](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6219/dezso)*:

If using `psql`, you still can make use of `\c` - especially if it does not require typing a password.